# Optimize this Python Code

Tags: python, performance

See the following equation:

[image]

I have made the following code for it:

```
def i_t(t, t_s, t_max, i_min, i_max):
    if t >= t_max:
        return i_max
    elif t_s <= t < t_max:
        s = (i_max - i_min) / (t_max - t_s)
        return s*(t-t_s)
    else:
        return 0
x_real = pd.DataFrame([[0.322,0.062,0.045,0.05,0.094,0.067,0.045,0.042,0.009,0.047,0.109,0.077,0.051,0.046,0.019,
                      0.033,0.122,0.085,0.028,0.344,0.208,0.166,0.247,0.231,0.149,0.157,0.137,0.061,0.118,0.135,
                      0.152,0.155,0.243,0.27,0.321,0.386,0.444,0.464,0.382,0.397,0.41,0.397,0.42,0.368,0.356,0.322,
                      0.295,0.309,3],
                     [1.01,0.661,0.627,0.662,0.626,0.647,0.638,0.633,0.653,1.07,0.664,0.628,0.661,1.138,1.403,
                      0.998,0.634,0.639,0.618,0.654,0.619,0.655,0.621,0.652,0.624,0.634,0.644,0.623,0.654,0.616,
                      0.653,0.62,0.643,0.635,0.624,0.65,0.621,1.044,1.335,1.371,1.341,1.376,1.386,1.378,1.404,1.366,
                      1.413,1.388,2],
                     [0.484,0.429,0.3,0.146,0.146,0.264,0.242,0.147,0.146,0.16,0.265,0.252,0.144,0.13,0.088,0.194,
                      0.199,0.115,0.088,0.088,0.136,0.572,0.365,0.222,0.369,0.242,0.732,0.457,0.339,0.285,0.645,
                      0.461,0.813,2.317,1.745,0.89,0.193,1.419,1.586,1.068,0.844,0.35,0.355,0.338,0.323,0.331,0.336,
                      0.322,1],
                     [0.467,0.561,0.272,0.265,0.235,0.246,0.258,0.249,0.247,0.265,0.259,0.259,0.405,0.24,0.222,
                      0.134,0.114,0.219,0.573,0.268,0.522,0.233,0.852,1.78,0.397,0.27,2.229,2.738,0.404,0.415,0.527,
                      1.174,2.506,2.333,1.367,1.871,3.831,3.043,1.347,1.026,1.17,1.021,0.837,0.97,0.84,0.861,0.853,
                      1.783,1]], columns=['00:29:59','00:59:59','01:29:59','01:59:59','02:29:59','02:59:59',
                                          '03:29:59','03:59:59','04:29:59','04:59:59','05:29:59','05:59:59',
                                          '06:29:59','06:59:59','07:29:59','07:59:59','08:29:59','08:59:59',
                                          '09:29:59','09:59:59','10:29:59','10:59:59','11:29:59','11:59:59',
                                          '12:29:59','12:59:59','13:29:59','13:59:59','14:29:59','14:59:59',
                                          '15:29:59','15:59:59','16:29:59','16:59:59','17:29:59','17:59:59',
                                          '18:29:59','18:59:59','19:29:59','19:59:59','20:29:59','20:59:59',
                                          '21:29:59','21:59:59','22:29:59','22:59:59','23:29:59','23:59:59','Code'])
x_labels = x_real.columns[0:48]
imin = 0
imax = 0.9
time_arr = np.arange(48)
x_8 = pd.DataFrame(columns=x_labels)
for i, row in x_real.iterrows():
    x_aux = pd.DataFrame(columns=x_labels)
    if row['Code'] == 1:
        it = []
        ts = random.choice(x_labels[36:39])
        tmax = random.choice([t for t in x_labels if t > ts])
        ts = x_real.columns.get_loc(ts)
        tmax = x_real.columns.get_loc(tmax)
        for t in time_arr:
            it.append(i_t(t, ts, tmax, imin, imax))
        x_aux.loc[i] = it
        x_aux.loc[i] = np.asarray([1 - x for x in it])*x_real.iloc[i, 0:48]
        x_aux = x_aux.squeeze(axis=0)
        x_aux = pd.concat([x_aux, x_real.iloc[i, 48:]])
        x_aux = x_aux.to_frame()
        x_8 = pd.concat([x_8, x_aux.T])
    elif row['Code'] == 2:
        it = []
        ts = random.choice(x_labels[15:33])
        tmax = random.choice([t for t in x_labels if t > ts])
        ts = x_real.columns.get_loc(ts)
        tmax = x_real.columns.get_loc(tmax)
        for t in time_arr:
            it.append(i_t(t, ts, tmax, imin, imax))
        x_aux.loc[i] = it
        x_aux.loc[i] = np.asarray([1 - x for x in it])*x_real.iloc[i, 0:48]
        x_aux = x_aux.squeeze(axis=0)
        x_aux = pd.concat([x_aux, x_real.iloc[i, 48:]])
        x_aux = x_aux.to_frame()
        x_8 = pd.concat([x_8, x_aux.T])
    else:
        it = []
        ts = random.choice(x_labels[12:35])
        tmax = random.choice([t for t in x_labels if t > ts])
        ts = x_real.columns.get_loc(ts)
        tmax = x_real.columns.get_loc(tmax)
        for t in time_arr:
            it.append(i_t(t, ts, tmax, imin, imax))
        x_aux.loc[i] = it
        x_aux.loc[i] = np.asarray([1 - x for x in it])*x_real.iloc[i, 0:48]
        x_aux = x_aux.squeeze(axis=0)
        x_aux = pd.concat([x_aux, x_real.iloc[i, 48:]])
        x_aux = x_aux.to_frame()
        x_8 = pd.concat([x_8, x_aux.T])
```

I am getting the results i expect, but since the data i am working on has around `350` thousands rows, it takes forever to run.

My pandas dataframe has `49`columns. Each row is the data of a consumer. The first `48` columns contain half-hour measurements of a variable (hence we have 1 day of data at each row) for a single consumer. The last column `x_real['Code']` contains a code that represents the type of consumers (it can be `1`, `2` or `3`). Below some pictures to get the idea of the data i am working on:

[image]

[image]

So, i need to apply that equation for each row (consumer) of my dataset. And it depends of the value of `'Code'`, because there are different range of start, `ts`, and max time, `tmax`. Based on those random `ts` and `tmax`, i need to calculate the slope, `s`, to determine the values of `it` so i can finally determine my `x_8` dataframe.

How could i optmize this code, so it can run faster? In resume, i need to determine the `s` value for each row, to be able to compute `it` and finally
create my `x_8` dataframe with the values of `it`.

Comment: This code does not run because x_real etc. are undefined. Additionally, when pasting examples, use text and not images.

Comment: Put the concerns about the code in the body of the question. Tell us what the code does (what is the equation for?) in the title of the question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Is my code on topic?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Reinderien Sorry for that. I have added the first `4` rows of `x_real` and `x_label`. That should solve the issue.

Comment: You might also want to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I have a semi-vectorised proposal and a prepared review, but cannot post it until you fix the issues with this question and vote to have it re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

A few improvements I could see, which you could implement to handle such large datasets and speed up the program, are vectorized operations so it should perform on the entire dataframe at once.

You could also implement parallel processing which should be able to speed up the code significantly, however your hardware would determine how effective this would be for you.

A couple other options would be to implement memory-mapped arrays or streaming data processing techniques to load and process the data in smaller chunks and, as this code acts as a scraper for your dataset, I would always recommend including a caching function in any scraper based code.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the good suggestions of @Robert3737, you may also consider to reshape your data in some other way.

For instance, you can divide your data according the categorical number and processes each batch in a vectorized way if they require different computation of the slope and of the other parameters, and at the end put them together again.

Moreover, you may also consider to reshape your data in a so-called "long" format, that is, from each row get 48 rows with the following columns:

```
| Code | timestamp | value |
```

In this way you can operate through groupbys and aggregations (which are vectorized) to compute the required quantities.